# Webscraping vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information off of a bloomberg website, no subscription needed. The url is : http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/BCOMTR:IND. The code runs perfectly with no bugs however the cell i am trying to paste my innertext into remains blank. Any idea as to why I'm unable to retrieve it?

Here is my code:

```
Dim TDelements As Object
Dim TDelement As Object

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
sURL = "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/BCOMTR:IND"

With oIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True

    Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While oIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A5").Select

    Set Iedoc = oIE.document
    For i = 0 To Iedoc.all.Length - 1

        Set TDelements = Iedoc.getElementsByClassName("cell__value cell__value")
        ' loop thru each row in our table
        ' note we skip the first (header) row below ...
        For Each TDelement In TDelements
            If TDelement.className = ("cell__value cell__value") Then
                ActiveCell.Value = TDelement(3).innerText
            End If
        Next
        Exit For
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried any de-bugging? For example, how do you know that your code is entering each loop? Do you need another `Exit For` statement inside your `If` block?

Comment: you're also iterating though a collection of objects, set by looking for a class name - and then testing to see if they have the same class name that they were collected with....

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer!

```
    Dim htmCol As HTMLElementCollection

Set doc = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/BCOMTR:IND" & Code
    .send
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    .abort
End With

Set htmCol = doc.getElementsByClassName("cell__value cell__value")(2)

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A5").Select

ActiveCell.Value = htmCol.innerText
```

End Sub